# Sanding a newly sealed deck

Tags: deck

We have a 3 year old wooden deck. it was just recently sealed. there is a few rough spots where someone may end up with a splinter..can we lightly sand those spots without damaging the sealant?? Please help !!

Comment: Not possible, the sealant is only few microns thick, so you will surely sand it off when trying to remove the rough spots. So bite the bullet and start  with grid 200 till you have removed the rough spots. Then re-apply sealant

Comment: You shouldn't have to reseal the entire deck. After light sanding feather in the the sealant in that area.

Comment: If it's _just_ a sealant, you probably won't have to worry much about 'feathering' in the edges, as the sealant won't offer much coloration beyond the faded grey of the 3 year old wood. What you _will_ notice is that after sanding, you'll have some nice light colored fresh wood that will be a different color. Don't worry, even with sealant on it, it'll be close enough in color within a year or so that nobody will notice.

Comment: What is the sealant? Is it solid surface like Varathane or Urethane?   Personally I prefer an penetrating oil like Pentofin. It's easy to touch up. Yeah you gotta lightly sand it every few years and re-apply, but in my neck of the woods (PNW) with all the rain/snow, solid surface finishes don't hold up well.

Comment: I agree the type of sealant makes a difference, an oil seal should match up well after sanding.